# Elasticsearch: No alive nodes found in your cluster & test connection gets failed

Tags: catalog, reindex, elasticsearch, magento2.4

**I have run this command:**

> `composer show elasticsearch/elasticsearch`

then all stats of elastic search runs perfectly. Attached is the screenshot. Also, I have configured in the admin panel. The screenshot attached as well then why my connection always failed. Please fix this solution & alive cluster found error comes in your cluster.

[image]

[image]

Comment: elastic search will not work on localhost

Comment: so what do I have to change?

Comment: I am running my website on cpanel online.

Comment: try to switch it back to elastic search 6 or may be deafult coz sql  search has been deprecated

Comment: What do I change in Elastic search & Elastic serach hostname

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, I have installed Elasticsearch in my Linux Mint & It's working fine. Here is the steps.

Run the below command to Install Elasticsearch In locally.

Download and install the public signing key :

`wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -`

Installing from the APT repositoryedit

You may need to install the apt-transport-https package on Debian before proceeding :

`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`

Save the repository definition to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list :

`echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list`

You can install the Elasticsearch Debian package with :

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch`

Elasticsearch is not started automatically after installation. How to start and stop Elasticsearch depends on whether your system uses SysV `init` or `systemd` (used by newer distributions).

`ps -p 1`

Running Elasticsearch with SysV `init` : Use the `update-rc.d` command to configure Elasticsearch to start automatically when the system boots up :

`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`

Elasticsearch can be started and stopped using the `service` command :

`sudo -i service elasticsearch start`

`sudo -i service elasticsearch stop`

Configure Apache and Elasticsearch : Set up a proxy (Set up a proxy for Apache 2.4)

Enable mod_proxy as follows :

`a2enmod proxy_http` or `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

Use a text editor to open /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Add the following directive at the top of the file :

`Listen 8080`

Add the following at the bottom of the file :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache :

`service apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`

Verify the proxy works by entering the following command :

For example, if your proxy uses port 8080:

`curl -i http://localhost:8080/_cluster/health`

If curl request success then messages display like below :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 06:05:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 389

{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":50.0}

Go to `Admin Panel -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`. Change the settings like below.

`Search Engine : Search Engine7`

`Elasticsearch Server Hostname : localhost`

`Elasticsearch Server Port : 8080`

`Elasticsearch Index Prefix : magento2`

`Enable Elasticsearch HTTP Auth : No`

`Elasticsearch Server Timeout : 15`

Now save the configuration & run below cache clean command.

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Now click on `Test Connection` button.

After successful you will receive `Successful! Test again?` in `Test Connection` button.

Ref : [Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/es-config-apache.html) & [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html)

For More [Click here](https://vrajeshpatel.in/2020/08/23/magento-2-4-0-getting-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch/)

Comment: I am using on windows 10 & I have already a elastic field in my magento2 admin

Comment: Try Test Connection. Success or Fail ?

Comment: Is this link correct @ArunKumar

Comment: Connection failed on elasticsearch:internal and on localhost 9200 port test is failed as well

Comment: Have you added virtual host ?  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf in file ?

Comment: I am using my website on hosting server and what is this virtual host please explain

Comment: Raise ticket for your hosting server.

Comment: What is virtual host and for what I have to raise ticket please explain in detail?

Comment: For Locally I have added : <VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>

For you server you can ask to support.

Comment: Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Not for now. I have this information only.

Comment: Hi @Vrajesh Patel

Comment: Have you fixed ?

Comment: No now I am getting this error:

Comment: Catalog Search index process unknown error:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method GET is not allowed for this URL.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 405 Method Not Allowed
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: I was getting same but I have added in virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file & restart apache. After working.

Comment: I m working online

Answer (score 0):

I was struggled yesterday with the exact same issue (*No alive nodes found in your cluster*) and I've figured it out.

I'm using Elasticsearch in a production setup, in a 3-node cluster. In order to be fully secured & to enable authentication, I've also followed ([from the Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/secure-cluster.html)) the steps to configure TLS communications between nodes & Kibana.

The fact is that I was using an auto-generated non-trusted CA file to sign all my cert & key files. But from the point of view of PHP (on Magento's side), this non-trusted CA file was silently causing Magento to refuse the connection to my Elastic cluster, even though my connection parameters were correct.

So I've added this CA file into the OS CA directory. I'm using Debian 10, to do this:

1. Get the CA file (in PEM format) from the Elastic node where you generated all the certificates.

   - You must have run this command during your configuration :

   ```
   /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca elastic-stack-ca.p12
   ```

   - That command must have generated a ZIP file and in that and ZIP, there's a folder named **`kibana`**, this folder contains the right CA file format to copy to your Magento server.
   - Copy that `elasticsearch-ca.pem` file to your Magento server.
2. From your Magento server, copy the `elasticsearch-ca.pem` into your `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, **but with a .crt file extension !** :

```
root@mgto2-server:~# cp elasticsearch-ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/elasticsearch-ca.crt
```

3. Now, update your available certificates using this command (Debian 10) :

```
root@mgto2-server:~# update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

Note the **1 added** here.

Finally restart Apache2 & PHP-FPM (if you're using PHP-FPM, of course ;-) ) and you should be able to initiate a successful HTTPS connection to your Elasticsearch instance from Magento.

Hope it helps.